# Problems to install Mocha: "Error Parsing Json"

Tags: json, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I have a problem installing mocha. I try to install mocha with the following line:

```
npm install -g mocha
```

This is the output which I get (If I type the http://registry.npmjs.org/mocha into the browser I'm able to see the json data):

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
npm ERR! <html><head>
npm ERR! <title>404 Not Found</title>
npm ERR! </head><body>
npm ERR! <h1>Not Found</h1>
npm ERR! <p>The requested URL /mocha was not found on this server.</p>
npm ERR! </body></html>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:203:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
node_modules\request\request.js:123:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\request\request.js:893:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:844:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "mocha"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\myName
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myName\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: can you access [https://registry.npmjs.org/](https://registry.npmjs.org/) ?

Comment: if so, can you access [https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha](https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the npm web site sometimes flakes out, which causes `npm` commands to fail. I've seen cases where I had to just retry a few times until the command works. (Having to go through a proxy to access the net could also cause issues but I don't think the error message would be like above.)

Comment: I tried the commend several times and still got the problem. I also tried to install Mocha after I downloaded the package from github. Which causes the same issue but with another package (e.g. http://registry.npmjs.org/debug). However If I open them in my webbrowser I can see the json content. I'm having a prox by the way (set also the config for that already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying to resolve this issue I found this solution: 
The problem which I had is connected to the proxy settings of npm. Which means that npm was not able to load the json file correctly. 
You have to set the proxy settings first:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@YourProxy:Port
npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@YourProxy:Port (If you have one)
```